# How can I fix module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot' Or code a Slash Snipe bot correctly?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've just started learning how to code and I'm super new to everything. I usually watch YouTube videos that kinda of teach me everything but I've been having trouble with coding my /snipe bot as it always says "error: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is the code so far, not including the snipe code commands

```
    import discord

bot = discord.bot(intents = discord.intents.default())

servers = []

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): 
  print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}.")

bot.run('token')
```

Any way I can fix this? or would there better another better way to code a /snipe bot

Comment: It's `discord.Client`.

Answer (score 0):

As like in the comment from `3nws`. First you should determine `client` that make it equal to `bot`

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=[your prefix here])
```

Then you can go using `bot` instead `client`. It just like nicknames when you are calling your friend

```
@bot.event()
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}.")
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by removing the first code block, which is confusing and redundant.